# Creating a proxy instance failed with COMException (IIS, Windows Server 2012, NHibernate)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, reflection.emit, windows-server-2012

Been running a site for 4+ years on NHibernate. We recently moved the site to a Windows Server 2012 machine and updated NHibernate to 3.3.
After about a month on the new server we began to see the following exceptions

```
NHibernate.HibernateException: Creating a proxy instance failed ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(RuntimeAssembly containingAssembly, Boolean emitSymbolInfo, String name, String filename, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr& pInternalSymWriter, ObjectHandleOnStack retModule, Boolean fIsTransient, Int32& tkFile)
at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModuleInternalNoLock(String name, String fileName, Boolean emitSymbolInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModuleInternal(String name, String fileName, Boolean emitSymbolInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(String name, String fileName, Boolean emitSymbolInfo)
```

A restart of the application pool solves the problem for a while.

It happens about once a week, it affects different entities everytime, and other parts of the site (that also uses NHibernate) continues to work.

Full stacktrace below:

```
NHibernate.HibernateException: Creating a proxy instance failed ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(RuntimeAssembly containingAssembly, Boolean emitSymbolInfo, String name, String filename, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr& pInternalSymWriter, ObjectHandleOnStack retModule, Boolean fIsTransient, Int32& tkFile)
at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModuleInternalNoLock(String name, String fileName, Boolean emitSymbolInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModuleInternal(String name, String fileName, Boolean emitSymbolInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(String name, String fileName, Boolean emitSymbolInfo)
at NHibernate.Proxy.DynamicProxy.DefaultProxyAssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder, String moduleName)
at NHibernate.Proxy.DynamicProxy.ProxyFactory.CreateUncachedProxyType(Type baseType, Type[] baseInterfaces)
at NHibernate.Proxy.DynamicProxy.ProxyFactory.CreateProxyType(Type baseType, Type[] interfaces)
at NHibernate.Proxy.DynamicProxy.ProxyFactory.CreateProxy(Type instanceType, IInterceptor interceptor, Type[] baseInterfaces)
at NHibernate.Proxy.DefaultProxyFactory.GetProxy(Object id, ISessionImplementor session)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at NHibernate.Proxy.DefaultProxyFactory.GetProxy(Object id, ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.CreateProxy(Object id, ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.CreateProxy(Object id, ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.CreateProxyIfNecessary(LoadEvent event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType options, IPersistenceContext persistenceContext)
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.ProxyOrLoad(LoadEvent event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType options)
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.OnLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType loadType)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType loadType)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.InternalLoad(String entityName, Object id, Boolean eager, Boolean isNullable)
at NHibernate.Type.EntityType.ResolveIdentifier(Object id, ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Type.EntityType.ResolveIdentifier(Object value, ISessionImplementor session, Object owner)
at NHibernate.Engine.TwoPhaseLoad.InitializeEntity(Object entity, Boolean readOnly, ISessionImplementor session, PreLoadEvent preLoadEvent, PostLoadEvent postLoadEvent)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.InitializeEntitiesAndCollections(IList hydratedObjects, Object resultSetId, ISessionImplementor session, Boolean readOnly)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.LoadCollection(ISessionImplementor session, Object id, IType type)
at NHibernate.Loader.Collection.CollectionLoader.Initialize(Object id, ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Persister.Collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.Initialize(Object key, ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.OnInitializeCollection(InitializeCollectionEvent event)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.InitializeCollection(IPersistentCollection collection, Boolean writing)
at NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.Initialize(Boolean writing)
at NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.Read()
at NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
at XXX.YYY.Services.FluentMdx.Queries.PrioMatrixQuery.SetupDimensionCollector(IDimensionCollector dimensionCollector)
at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__12()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) at NHibernate.Proxy.DefaultProxyFactory.GetProxy(Object id, ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.CreateProxy(Object id, ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.CreateProxy(Object id, ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.CreateProxyIfNecessary(LoadEvent event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType options, IPersistenceContext persistenceContext)
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.ProxyOrLoad(LoadEvent event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType options)
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.OnLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType loadType)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType loadType)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.InternalLoad(String entityName, Object id, Boolean eager, Boolean isNullable)
at NHibernate.Type.EntityType.ResolveIdentifier(Object id, ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Type.EntityType.ResolveIdentifier(Object value, ISessionImplementor session, Object owner)
at NHibernate.Engine.TwoPhaseLoad.InitializeEntity(Object entity, Boolean readOnly, ISessionImplementor session, PreLoadEvent preLoadEvent, PostLoadEvent postLoadEvent)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.InitializeEntitiesAndCollections(IList hydratedObjects, Object resultSetId, ISessionImplementor session, Boolean readOnly)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.LoadCollection(ISessionImplementor session, Object id, IType type)
at NHibernate.Loader.Collection.CollectionLoader.Initialize(Object id, ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Persister.Collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.Initialize(Object key, ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.OnInitializeCollection(InitializeCollectionEvent event)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.InitializeCollection(IPersistentCollection collection, Boolean writing)
at NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.Initialize(Boolean writing)
at NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.Read()
at NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
at XXX.YYY.Services.FluentMdx.Queries.PrioMatrixQuery.SetupDimensionCollector(IDimensionCollector dimensionCollector)
at XXX.YYY.Services.FluentMdx.Queries.QueryBuilder.b__1(IDimensionCollector x)
at XXX.YYY.Services.FluentMdx.Queries.QueryBuilder.BuildQuery(IFluentMdxFilterCommand mdxFilterQueryCommand)
at XXX.YYY.Services.FluentMdx.FluentMdxRepository.ExecuteQuery(IMdxQueryBuilder mdxQueryBuilder)
at XXX.YYY.Services.Result.PrioMatrixRenderService.GetChartEngine(IReadOnlyQuerySettings querySettings, ChartSettingsModel settingsModel)
at XXX.YYY.MVC.Controllers.PrioMatrixRenderController.RenderChart(QuerySettings queryable, ChartSettingsModel chartSettings)
at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__12()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

Comment: @Tico, in the future, please use `>` to format errors, so all the text is on the screen without scrolling.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have the CLSID that is complaining about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did finally test it out with a different identity on the AppPool and since then we haven't seen the problem.

We dont know what causes it, but changing identity removes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2009/11/06/a-com-server-application-may-stop-working-on-windows-server-2008.aspx

Does this help? Another workaround is to disable profile unloading in the IIS app pool.

Comment: We came across that link early in our investigations, we havent tried it since we dont feel comfortable enough to test in our production enviroment. In our next maintenance window we are going to test if changing the AppPool identity to a different user will fix it.